An estimate for equation $-\Delta G_2=8 \pi e^{G_2}-4 \pi \delta_p-4 \pi$ with $\int_{\Sigma} e^{G_2}=1$ on closed Riemannian surface.
I want to ask about the estimate for equation $$-\Delta G_2=8 \pi e^{G_2}-4 \pi \delta_p-4 \pi$$ with $\int_{\Sigma} e^{G_2}=1$ on unit volume closed Riemannian surface. Here $p$ is a fixed point on the surface.
If we have a sequence $u_2^\epsilon$ converges to $G_2$ in $H^{1, q}(\Sigma), q \in(1,2)$, and in $C_{\mathrm{loc}}^2(\Sigma \backslash\{p\})$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, how to prove that $\bar{u}_2^\epsilon$ is uniformly bounded?
By jensen's inequality $e^{\bar{G_2}} \le \int_{\Sigma} e^{G_2}=1$, which means $G_2$ is bounded from above, but I don't have any clue for the lower boundness.
